# ¿Por qué no está actualizando mi documento?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo un documento en MongoDB con un usuario al cual se le añade el campo de ingreso, el cual se ingresa mediante actualizacion del documento. Todo bien hasta ahí. Pero al querer actualizar nuevamente mi documento con otro campo, me dice que si actualizo pero la actualizacion no se ve reflejado en MongoDB. Uso como conexion a MongoDB Mongoose.

```
router.post('/income', (req, res, next) => {
const { income, name } = req.body

let errors = []

if (!income || income === 0) {
errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter the value of your income' })
}

if (errors.length > 0) {
 res.render('income', {
  errors,
  name,
  income
 })
} else {
// _id from user
const id = req.user._id
// Find the id and update that user
User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { income }, (err, req, res) => {
  if (err) { Error('Tienes un error actualizando Income') }
})
  .then(re => {
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Your income was save')
    res.redirect('/presupuesto/spend')
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(`You have an error ${err}`))
  }
})
```

El de arriba es el que funciona. El siguiente no.

```
router.post('/spend', (req, res, next) => {
 const { spense, cost } = req.body
 let errors = []

 if (!spense || !cost || spense === '' || cost === 0) {
  errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter a correct value' })
 }

 if (errors.length > 0) {
  res.render('spend', {
   errors,
   spense,
   cost
  })
 } else {
 // _id from user
 const id = req.user._id
 User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { spense }, (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err
 })
  .then(data => {
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Spend registered')
    res.redirect('spend')
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(`Tienes un error al guardar el valor. ${err}`))
 }
})
```

¿Que debería hacer para que funcione?

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución. Chic@s no sean como yo. Revisen TODO su código. El problema estaba en el esquema. No había agregado los campos que necesitaba. Lo se lo se perdonenme.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 username: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 password: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 date: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
 },
 income: {
  type: Number
 },
 spense: {
  type: String
 },
 cost: {
  type: Number
 }
})
```